# Delphi with TMS Web Core : hover and TWebCSSClass component

Tags: delphi, tms-web-core

What would be the best way to change the style of a control when the mouse is over ?

I didn't saw this feature with the TWebCSSClass component.

I can do this using TWebCSSClass components, but then I have to use the MouseEnter / MouseLeave events of the control. For example here, I use 2 TWebCSSClass components, and I change the ElementClassName of my control from *my-btn-style* to *my-btn-style-hover*
[using 2 differents TWebCSSClass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P22d8.png)

```
procedure TForm1.WebButton1MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
  webbutton1.ElementClassName := 'my-btn-style-hover';
end;

procedure TForm1.WebButton1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  webbutton1.ElementClassName := 'my-btn-style';
end;
```

it works, but then I will have to manage each control's mouse events individually, witch is not convenient if I want to do this for several similar controls.

I suppose there is a better way to manage this.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use two `TWebCSSClass` components.

For the first, use `CSSClassName "my-btn-style"`. For the second, use `CSSClassName "my-btn-style:hover"`. Just append `:hover` to the css class name.

Now set the `ElementClassName` of your button or other control to `"my-btn-style"`.

CSS properties in the second `TWebCSSClass` component will automatically override those in the first component when the mouse is over the button control.

The DFM of a sample form:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Width = 640
  Height = 480
  object WebButton1: TWebButton
    Left = 48
    Top = 72
    Width = 265
    Height = 81
    Caption = 'Click Me'
    ElementClassName = 'my-btn-style'
    HeightPercent = 100.000000000000000000
    WidthPercent = 100.000000000000000000
  end
  object cssButtonStyle: TWebCSSClass
    BackgroundColor = clHotLight
    CSSClassName = 'my-btn-style'
    Opacity = 1.000000000000000000
    Left = 72
    Top = 216
  end
  object cssButtonStyleHover: TWebCSSClass
    BackgroundColor = clGreen
    CSSClassName = 'my-btn-style:hover'
    Opacity = 1.000000000000000000
    Left = 176
    Top = 224
  end
end
```

Properties in the Object inspector:

[image]

[image]

[image]